# Sharepoint 2010 issue with exporting certain combination of columns from a view

Tags: excel, export

so I am encountering an issue where I am trying to export to excel..I modify my default view to include all the columns I need in the export. When I try to export, it's either hit or miss with certain combination of columns...

Why do some columns fail/work in export? I can have a column that fails everytime but when the same column is added to the view with a combination of other columns (at random)it works..

Example: Columns: A B C D E work, but column F fails all the time.. But when I remove "Column A" specifically from the view, it exports fine...

I would expect SP2010 would be able to export all combination of columns in any view.. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs generally due lookup columns threshold. And threshold hits because of multiple reasons like number of lookup columns in view, view’s WHERE condition or mandatory columns in the list.

- Reduce lookup columns from the View. Check if view contains how many
  lookup columns
- Reduce mandatory lookup columns from the list. Check if list contains
  how many mandatory lookup columns.